Buffer does it stay or get popped of the stack?
Just a quick question, lets say we have this following C code: 
int hello(){
 char arr[16];
 scanf("%s",arr);
 printf("%s",arr);
 return 0;
 }

I have a doubt that when the arr array is pushed on the stack and after the printf statement the leave instruction will be called restoring the ebp to esp both pointing to old ebp address we pushed at the start of prologue right? 
The main question is, what happened to the array arr that was pushed at the start during the exit of the function will it stay there or what if we call another function after that hello function will the array be stay there on the stack while the other function is executed?

I think you have a misconception about what "popped off the stack means".
In general, a stack has an "top", and we just don't care about what's beyond the top.  So when we "pop" the stack, we just move the pointer that we call the "top".  Whatever was beyond the top is still there, we just don't have an easy way to access it.  We don't immediately overwrite it, but we can overwrite it at any time we want.
Note that there are advanced/hacky program techniques such that I could recover what was in arr[16] after hello() returns. But these are very machine specific. They rely on the fact that arr[16] isn't actually erased until someone else needs that space.  And when they do need that space, they'll just ignore whatever was already there.
